# How to get the response data from AWS Lamda function using api gateway?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, lambda

I am a newer with AWS Lambda function to expect response an simple array like this:

I have setup a simple Lambda Node function `SimpleArray`:

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  const responseArray = [
    { name: "Item 1", value: 100 },
    { name: "Item 2", value: 200 },
    { name: "Item 3", value: 300 }
  ];
  
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(responseArray)
  };
};
```

In my Javascript client, i consume api by using fetch:

```
fetch(`${APP_ROOT_API_URL}/SimpleArray`, {
    mode: "no-cors",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
})
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(console.log)
```

I see the response is already there in Network tab

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r50kX.png)

But i received an error in console:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLEHx.png)

I tried to change it using `resp.text()`

```
fetch(`${APP_ROOT_API_URL}/SimpleArray`, {
    mode: "no-cors",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
})
.then((resp) => resp.json())
.then(console.log)
```

But what i received is a **Blank** text: ""

Comment: removed mode from request and try again

Comment: Thanks for your help @MeghshyamSonar. I got error CORS when i removed it. `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: It’s not a CORS error actually you are getting

Comment: Modify your handler and add try and catch, return 200 and response in try and in catch return 500 and error

Comment: It's still CORS issue when I add try catch in handler

Comment: I think that i should enable CORS for the handler

Comment: try the ans and see console logs, you don't need CORS

Comment: Let me know if doesn't help, I will delete ans

Comment: Check the ans, I updated the handler, try that.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda function looks fine. The issue might because you haven't enabled CORS in API Gateway.

**Step 1**: Adjust your client request:

- Remove `mode: "no-cors"` in your client request
- Add `headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }` to your request. And do 2 steps below:

**Step 2**: You need to enable CORS in API Gateway:

Go to API Gateway => CORS, set up:

1. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`: `*`
2. `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`: `*`
3. `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`: `*`

**Step 3**: Add route with method OPTIONS:

Go to API Gateway => Routes, create your same api route with OPTIONS method